# Provisoning profile Generate button not working

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning

New UI of developer account is not allowing to add new device in my provisioning profile. On top it shows to press Genrate button, but after modification Genrate button is still diable. Has anyone came across this.

I was able to add device successfully, but the problem is with modifying provisioning profile. 
I am admin of the account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using some special characters while giving name to your provisioning profile. Now apple has restricted to use "**_**" so if you are using **underscore** than don't use it.
It will enable generate button.

Hope it helps

Comment: This is silly :( As a developer we mostly use _ to seprate two words. Now I have to rename all my certificates. But anyways big thanks for the solution.