# Can't edit iOS Provisioning Profiles

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

It looks like the OS Provisioning Profiles is updated since last time I visited the site.

I'd like to update my provision profiles, to add an existing device into the profile, however the "Generate" button is always disabled and I can't press it.

So what's going on here? How should I update my profiles with this new site?

Thanks

Comment: See my answer [Provisoning profile Generate button not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964600/provisoning-profile-generate-button-not-working/15965472#15965472)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have used "**_**" in your provisioning profile name. As I have already given the answer of similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964600/provisoning-profile-generate-button-not-working/15965472#15965472)

Please remove **underscore** if you are using to enable **generate button** because apple has restricted to use this special character now.

Hope it helps

Comment: I think you are right, however the names with "_" is acceptable now

Answer (score 6):

On my screen:

- the provisioning profile `Managed by Xcode` has the `Edit` button grayed out (there is no `Generate` button anymore).
- the provisioning profile that is not managed by Xcode can be edited online.

So edit the profile via Xcode.